# Looking for ports used by hadoop and all the ports used by them

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform, mapr

Is there any resource online where one can find all the default ports used by hadoop or any hadoop service that can be installed?

This could ease a lot the setting up of a hadoop cluster.

Comment: Just ask Google. https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/08/hadoop-default-ports-quick-reference/ and https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/cdh_ig_ports_cdh5.html

Comment: @Ben At least link to the latest version of Ambari

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ports I know which can help you :

- 50070 : NAMENODE
- 3000  : GRAFANA
- 8080  : AMBARI UI
- 8088  : RESOURCE MANAGER
- 19888 : MAP-REDUCE JOBS
- 50075 : DATANODE
- 50090 : SECONDARY NAMENODE